# Mongo Find with Or in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to do the following but I don't think it's working wanted to know if it's correct

```
Collection.findOne({$or:[{userId: user._id},{collaboratorsIds: user._id}], $and:[{emailSlug:topicToFind}]});
```

Also if it doesn't find the collection does it return null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want:

```
{$and: [{emailSlug:topicToFind}, $or:[{userId: user._id},{collaboratorsIds: user._id}]]}
```

Think of it as a prefix notation: you're anding two expressions:

```
email==topicToFind
```

and

```
(userId == user._id or collaboratorsIds == user._id)
```

The second expression is again prefix or

Comment: Wow now I have the craziest use case let me know you have any ideas or suggestions

If the user is a collaborator on a topic but also has a topic with the same email slug the link mongo document is add to their topic and not the one their an invited collaborator.